# radio hide. show div class instead. on click of div select linked radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

trying to get this working. Instead of showing the normal radio, or replacing the radio with an image. i would like to replace it with a div i can dress up as a button and on hover the class changes and on click the class changes. but also on click the hidden radio is selected. but also require the label (label in reference to the text showing e.g as below .co.uk .com .net etc.) to be inside the div/button. or be able to add text to the div button. is this possible?

```
$(function() {
    $("input [name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after($("< class='radioButtonOff' />"));
        } else { 
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after($("<class='radioButtonOn' />"));
        }
    });

    $("input.radio").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src') == 'radiobuttonOn') {
            $(this).attr('src', 'radiobuttonOff');
            $(this).prev().attr('checked', 'false');
        } else { // its not checked, so check it
            $(this).attr('src', 'radioButtonOn');
            $(this).prev().attr('checked', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="domain_ext_ribbon">
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value="all"  />
      All</label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".co.uk"  />
      .co.uk</label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".com" />
      .com</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".net"  />
      .net</label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".org"  />
      .net</label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".biz" />
      .net</label></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
.radioButtonOff { width: 60px; height: 20px; background: #000000;}
.radioButtonHover { width: 60px; height: 20px; background: #666666;}
.radioButtonOn { width: 60px; height: 20px; background: #999999;}
```

Comment: Please don't edit out code mistakes after answerers point them out to you.

Comment: You're applying and if/else statement based on classes but classes aren't applied until AFTER that if else statement.

Comment: trying to insert a div to replace the default radio button.

Comment: `<class='radioButtonOn' />` is not a div. It's ... well... nothing but malformed code.

Comment: true i have not implemented the markup. should it insert <div class="radioButtonOn"> label </div> ???

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a bug in your selector; you're missing the opening brace around your attribute filter.  So

```
$("input name='domain_ext']")
```

should be

```
$("input [name='domain_ext']")
```

---

Also, unless you're using specifically version 1.6 of jQuery, your code should work, but,

```
if ($(this).prop('checked'))
```

is the preferred way to check to see if a radio button is checked, as opposed to

```
if ($(this).attr('checked'))
```

See [this link](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/) for more information.

---

And of course this

```
$(this).after($("<class='radioButtonOn' />"));
```

doesn't really make much sense at all.  I think you meant:

```
$(this).after($("<div class='radioButtonOff' />"));
```

Comment: thanks ;) think i need to add a blur function for the hover state instead of doing it in css as hover?

Comment: yeah starting to think thats where it is going wrong. trying to get the div to act as a button to replace the default radio. and get the text into the div button.

Comment: still not seeing how to pull this together though. bit tricky